# Editable UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm following a tutorial on iOS-Blog: Editable UITableViewController - http://bit.ly/19sLmr4

and I'm having trouble getting this code to work, I downloaded the file from the site and that works perfectly but when I work through the code on the page it isn't working. Have I done something wrong?:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
  UITableViewCell* cell = [self parentCellFor:textField];
  if (cell)
  {
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
[self.tableView scrollToRollAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you have a typo as @MarkP mentions

Comment: oh, such a nooby thing to do. Thanks guys.

Comment: Don't worry, we've all been there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the code on the site:

http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/editable-uitableviewcontroller/ (none shortened link)

you will see that you have not taken it verbatim:

Where you have:

```
scrollToRollAtIndexPath
```

You need to have:

```
scrollToRowAtIndexPath
```

We have all been there :) Long night?